# Issue with @EnableCircuitBreaker annotation when running springboot service in local environment

Tags: spring, service, spring-boot, spring-cloud, hystrix

when using `@EnableCircuitBreaker` annotation with spring-cloud-services-dependencies 1.3.0 we are getting

> "Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.springframework.integration.amqp.support.DefaultAmqpHeaderMapper.outboundMapper()Lorg/springframework/integration/amqp/support/DefaultAmqpHeaderMapper;"
>   exception. We are not using any Messaging functionality in our
>   service.

We are using jetty embedded environment.

Can anyone suggest me how can I solve my issue?

Comment: I tried disabling the RabbitAutoConfiguration.class but still I see the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

The exception is thrown, cause your application tries to use some classes of spring integration for message queue, which cannot be found.

If you go further up the stacktrace you may find some classes with 'AutoConfiguration' that may show, which spring auto configuration has triggered the search for these missing classes.

You can also add the command line parameter [--debug](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-auto-configuration.html) to see what auto config is actually doing.

Once you identified the culprit you can exclude it from the auto configuration like this :

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {...})
```

Comment: Issue got fixed when I added Brixton.SR6 dependency in my pom